# How to mock a 100mb file using mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I need to test this feature "load a 100mb file and slice it"

I've been seeing some example like this

```
    describe('Class File', function () {
      let base64Image = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='

      describe('File Initialization', function () {
        it('can import a base64 source', function () {
          let file = new File(base64Image)
```

However, this file size is too small and not able to let me perform split tasks for each chunk 1mb size.

I could host a static file on as the test file for the test. But how do we do that is the point.

Any idea how to run pure frontend JS test and load big files into a File object? 
Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you *need* to dynamically generate it? Since I think it would be simpler to have an 100 meg static resource file. Sure, it takes up space in your repo but if it's more meaningful for the test, it's most likely the better option.

Comment: Git lfs would do here nicely.

Comment: can't you just '1'.repeat(1e8) after the base64 part

Comment: @emix. should be nothing to do with git.